# pytest mark parameterize a class attribute rather than a method argument

Tags: django, pytest

This is a simple example of a larger problem.  I would like to test out class methods which are based on class attributes with multiple tests like parameterize().  This example uses the same attribute 'view.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"]' for testing to see if it was modified both before and after the method was run.

Is there a way to parameterize the attribute tests?  Or is it necessary to restructure my code to be less readable to get the testing I want (using method arguments)?

```
# in tests/bookview.py
import pytest
from ..views import BookView


class BookViewTest:
    def SetUp(self):
        view = BookView()
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("view.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"],view.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"]", [("/\w/i", "\w"), ("/\d/i", "/\d/i"), ("/\w+/i", "\w+")])
    def test_reformat_javascript_regex_to_postgres_regex(self):
       view.reformat_javascript_regex_to_postgres_regex()


# elsewhere inside views.py
class BookView:
    ...
    def reformat_javascript_regex_to_postgres_regex(self):
        if self.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"].endswith('/i'):
            self.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"] = \
                self.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"][:-2]

       self.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"] = \
       self.form.cleaned_data["regexstring"] \
           .replace('^','\m') \
           .replace('/', '') \
           .replace('$', '\M')
```